# Await for subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a function using the library ngx-translate which returns an observable. So to use it I subscribe to the method and get the value I need. After that I want to do a return but I would like that the return happen after the value has been gotten.

This is my code:

```
test(textePage: string[], params?: Object){
    let textToSpeech: string;
    this._translateService.get(textePage).subscribe(res => {
        textToSpeech = (Object.keys(res).map(e=>res[e])).join('');
    });
    return textToSpeech;
}
```

I would like something like:

```
test(textePage: string[], params?: Object){
    let textToSpeech: string;
    this._translateService.get(textePage).subscribe(res => {
        textToSpeech = (Object.keys(res).map(e=>res[e])).join('');
        return textToSpeech;
    });
}
```

But I know it is not the best way.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show how you want to use the result. You cannot synchronize an async request at all. So the returnvalue will always be an Observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Observable methods like `map`:

```
return this._translateService.get(textePage).pipe(
  map(res => (Object.keys(res).map(e=>res[e])).join(''))
);
```

Now in order to use this you will have to call `this.test(textePage, params).subscribe` in your component to set the property of the component. You can also use the `| async` pipe which will handle the subscription for you.

Comment: Just as I posted my answer yours popped up :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `map` operator as follows:

```
test(textePage: string[], params?: Object){
  return this._translateService.get(textePage).pipe(
    map(res => {
      return (Object.keys(res).map(e=>res[e])).join('');
    })
  );
}

...

test(myStrings, myParam).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```